# Using Shapeless Poly in another method

Tags: scala, implicit, generic-programming, shapeless, polymorphic-functions

I'm trying to use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) [Poly](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) in another method like this:

```
object poly extends Poly1 {
  implicit val caseInt = at[Int](_.toString)
  implicit val caseString = at[String](_.toString)
}

def f[A, P <: Poly](a: A, p: P) = println(p(a))
```

this gives

```
could not find implicit value for parameter cse: shapeless.poly.Case[p.type,shapeless.::[A,shapeless.HNil]]
```

Any suggestion on how to make this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Poly.apply` requires an implicit evidence of the `Case` implicit, which is what you provide it via the `at[A]` helper method.

We need to add that same implicit requirement to `f`:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.PolyDefns.Case

def f[A, P <: Poly](a: A, p: P)(implicit cs: Case.Aux[p.type, shapeless.::[A, HNil], String]) = 
  println(p(a))
```

Comment: It works! How silly I am. One question though: is a clean way to use type `P` instead of `p.type`? I imagine that I will have to put my implicit `case` in scope somewhere right?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't really work. When I call it like this `f(1, poly)`, the compiler cannot find the implicit again. I'm using Scala 2.11.12 if that is related.

Comment: @MinhThai I was running this on 2.12, I'll try 2.11 once I'm next to a computer.

Comment: thanks, it does run. Not sure what happened to my local build though